# Excel Date calculation

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

Excel calculating date in two different ways. When adding two date's (even no of date's), it displaying serial date. But when i add three date's (odd no of date's), it displaying in normal date. How excel date calculation working...

[image]

Comment: Are you sure its not just a format issue? Try to right click the A-column (it will select entire A) do "Format Cells..." and chose a Date format.

Answer (score 1):

Dates in Excel are stored as numbers - numeric value of "1.000" equals 01-Jan-1900 00:00 - with fractions representing the time of the day (e.g. 1/24 = 1 hour)

Formatting cells as "Date" just changes the representation

[image: sample date calculation]

You normally do not "add dates", you add/subtract a number of days (or fractions thereof) to/from a date, either directly or by use of Excel functions. So I cannot imagine in which context the above calculation could make any sense.

It does make sense to substract 2 dates to get the # of days in between - do not forget to set the format of the result to "General" as the default is to keep the date format, and add 1 to get a day count containing both cornering dates (e.g. `=DEnd-DStart+1`)

You can though add times and present them with overflowing seconds, minutes or hours by using custom formats like [s], [m]:ss, [h]:mm:ss etc.